# Dataframe doesn't append to MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to coding and this my first project. So far I've pieced together what I have through Googling, Tutorials and Stack.

So far I've manage to get data which I'm scraping from RSS into an SQL database. However, when I run the script the new data doesn't append. It just updates with the most recent feed entries, erasing what was previously there.

I'm not sure what I've written incorrectly as I've added append in the function. Apologise is this is a really daft question but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import feedparser
import time

rawrss = ['http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml',
          'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/',
          'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/feeds/index.xml',
          'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/',
         ]

time = time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S')
summary = 'text'

posts = []
for url in rawrss:
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for post in feed.entries:
        posts.append((time, post.title, post.link, summary))

df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['article_time','article_title','article_url', 'article_summary']) # pass data to init
df.set_index(['article_time'], inplace=True)

import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<dbname>?charset=utf8', encoding = 'utf-8')
engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rsstracker")
engine.execute("""CREATE TABLE rsstracker(article_time  varchar(255),
                article_title  varchar(255), 
                article_url  varchar(1000),
                article_summary varchar(1000))""")

df.to_sql(con=engine, name='rsstracker', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')
```

Comment: This `engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rsstracker")` could explain why _However, when I run the script the new data doesn't append_

Comment: Does this delete the table and start again every time I run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pointed out to me that I was dropping the tables, this then led me to realised that I was also trying to create a table every time.

I've now edited the initial code to create the table out and replaced it with an insert.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import feedparser
import time

rawrss = ['http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml',
          'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/',
          'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/feeds/index.xml',
          'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/',
         ]

time = time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S')
summary = 'text'

posts = []
for url in rawrss:
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for post in feed.entries:
        posts.append((time, post.title, post.link, summary))

df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['article_time','article_title','article_url', 'article_summary']) # pass data to init
df.set_index(['article_time'], inplace=True)

import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<dbname>?charset=utf8', encoding = 'utf-8')
engine.execute("INSERT INTO rsstracker VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s','%s')" % (time, post.title, post.link, summary))


df.to_sql(con=engine, name='rsstracker', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')
```